# show execution plan of a Oracle NoSQL query

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am trying to validate the usage of an index but I cannot find a command allowing to show the current execution plan?

```
SELECT /*+ FORCE_INDEX(Persons idx_income) */ 
* from Persons
WHERE income > 10000000 and age < 40;
```

Is there a command to do this ? How to validate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the shell utility, you can use the command `show query` that displays the query plan for a query.